MS Graph Subscription for Event Grid is failing with 400 Invalid Request
Background
I'm trying to create a graph subscription that will send notifications to my event grid that I have created in Azure. I want to track any changes to Entra Groups.
I've been trying to following the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/event-grid/subscribe-to-partner-events#high-level-steps
and here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/event-grid/subscribe-to-graph-api-events?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_Azure_EventGrid&tabs=http&tryIt=true&source=docs#code-try-9
Problem
I'm using Graph Explorer to create the subscription request.  I'm getting a 400 Invalid Request - Specified Resource is not supported for MSA requests".
Here's a screenshot showing what's happening in graph:

Here's a screenshot showing that I do have EventGrid enabled for my subscription:

And lastly, this shows you that I have added GraphAPI as a partner, and associated with the right resource group:

Questions/Additional Comments

Why am i getting this error?  I've tried to follow all the steps outlined in the documentation.  The expectation is that this subscription request will create the topic I have requested in the subscription.

I have tried both the 1.0 version and the beta Graph subscription API.  I get the same error message.

I actually want to subscribe to group changes so I originally had "groups" as the resource type in the POST request.  But when i tried it returned
"error": {
"code": "InternalServerError",
"message": "Unable to find target address"


So that's when I just tried the sample POST in the docs for "users".
Any suggestions or tips would be appreciated.
Edit 1
I've tried to add permissions to a specific user like this:

And then when i sign in to MS Graph with that user account and retry this is what I get:

Edit 2
When I sign into graph with the new user I created, I see this:

In order to consent, it prompts me to sign in as ad admin, which I do.  I go through the entire list, and I grant consent to everything I think I need:

And i do it for the Users, and Groups category as well.  But once I'm done, I'm noticing that I'm now signed into Graph with the admin account instead of the new user1.mydomain.onmicrosoft.com.
When I sign out and sign back into graph with the correct account, the consent prompt is still there.
EDIT 3
Additional artifacts that might be related to my issue:
When I sign into graph using the new user, i see this notice:

I go through the prompts and set up authenicator, and then I end up with this:

Lastly, in case it helps, I've tried to add the permissions using the Entra Admin Center for this new user but I can't find user.read.all.  I'm pretty new to the Azure Platform so I imagine I'm not in the right spot.  But here's what I've tried:


what are the API permissions for the app registration

@DMabulage i don't have an app registration created.  Didn't realize I needed one for graph explorer requests.  can you point me to an article that would explain how to configure this?  i have a separate resource group, azure function app, app registration created.  But this app will be a reader / subscriber to the event grid, once I get the ms graph subscription working.

Could you confirm what type of account you used to sign in to Graph Explorer? personal Microsoft account or account ending with .onmicrosoft.com?

The error occurs if you are trying to create MS Graph Subscription by signing with personal Microsoft accounts to Graph Explorer.
I created one Partner configuration for Sri resource group by authorizing Microsoft Graph API to create resources like this:

Initially, I too same error when I tried to create MS Graph subscription by signing with personal Microsoft account like Outlook as below:

To resolve the error, sign in with tenant admin user account ending with .onmicrosoft.com and make sure to grant either User.Read.All or Group.Read.All permission based on resource type.
In my case, I logged in with tenant user account with User.Read.All permission and created subscription successfully for users resource like this:
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/subscriptions
{
"changeType": "Updated, Deleted, Created",
"notificationUrl": "EventGrid: ?azuresubscriptionid=subId&resourcegroup=Sri&partnertopic=EntraGroupChanges&location=eastus",
"lifecycleNotificationUrl": "EventGrid: ?azuresubscriptionid=subId&resourcegroup=Sri&partnertopic=EntraGroupChanges&location=eastus",
"resource": "users",
"expirationDateTime": "2024-11-08T00:00:00Z",
"clientState": "secretClientValue"
}

Response:

To create MS Graph Subscription for groups resource, make sure to grant Group.Read.All permissions and "resource" value to groups as below:
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/subscriptions
{
"changeType": "Updated, Deleted, Created",
"notificationUrl": "EventGrid: ?azuresubscriptionid=subId&resourcegroup=Sri&partnertopic=EntraGroupChanges&location=eastus",
"lifecycleNotificationUrl": "EventGrid: ?azuresubscriptionid=subId&resourcegroup=Sri&partnertopic=EntraGroupChanges&location=eastus",
"resource": "groups",
"expirationDateTime": "2024-11-08T00:00:00Z",
"clientState": "secretClientValue"
}

Response:

When I checked the same in Portal, Partner Topic created successfully as below:


So I've tried to grant those specific permissions to the user.  But I still get an error.  Please see Edit 1'

And Edit 2.  Thank you!

Could you include image where User.Read.All and Group.Read.All permissions are consented for signed in user?

Note that, there is no need to grant consent to all permissions present in Graph Explorer. Just search for User.Read.All and Group.Read.All and grant consent to those permissions in Graph Explorer.

Please see edit 3.  That's what happens when I try to sign in with the new user to explorer and try granting just the User.Read.All or Group.Read.All

is there any way to add these permissions to the new user via the Entra Admin Center?  I'm poking around there right now.

If you are running query in Graph Explorer, then you need to grant permissions to user under Modify permissions tab by signing in with new user account in Graph Explorer.

Yes makes sense but the problem is that  it won’t let me add those permissions

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
